# what is the classpath for a project in mulestudio?

Tags: xslt, classpath, mule

While defining a XSLT in mule, in studio I am forced to define one of the attributes as

```
    xsl-file="src/main/resources/myFile.xsl"
```

But, if i try to deploy it in standalone, I am forced to modify this attribute as

```
    xsl-file="myFile.xsl"
```

Is there a way that I can write code in one of these ways and use it in both standalone and mulestudio? Is there a way to determine/set classpath for a mule project in mulestudio ?

note: I am using mulestudio 3.5.0 and mule 3.4.0 in standalone

Answer (score 0):

I use the latter (without src/main...) and don't have any problems running application through Studio or deployed on standalone server. I do however, run it as 'Mule application with Maven'. Maybe that's the case?

More about that: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Converting+Studio+into+Maven